# Postgres: How to calculate distance for a set of geography points?

Tags: postgresql, gps, postgis

I'm using Postgres v13.

I couldn't find a clear example of how to achieve this basic calculation. I'm totally confused about how to handle geometry and geography points.

I have a table that stores points in the format `geography(Point, 4326)` alongside their timestamp.

I need to obtain the total distance in meters between timestamps A and B, and I need it to be super specific using spherical calculations. To be clear, there may be N points.

So far I've been using this query, but the distance is way off for long distances and I don't understand if there is any difference in creating a line using geometry points or geography points:

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_MakeLine(lh.position::geometry order by report_time), TRUE)
FROM location_history AS lh
WHERE lh.device_id = 1
AND lh.report_time BETWEEN '2022-10-10T13:25:00.000Z' AND '2022-10-11T13:25:00.000Z'
GROUP BY lh.device_id;
```

Does this query make sense? `ST_MakeLine` only accepts geometry points and confuses me. Is there another way of creating a line with geography points?

`ST_Distance` is used in every example I could find, but it just compares 2 points!

Thanks!

Comment: Well perhaps you need a better explanation since *distance in meters between timestamps* makes no since at all. The rest sounds like what you are looking for is [ST_Perimeter()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Perimeter.html) function in Postgis.

Comment: I obviously want the distance between all the points in the specified interval. Why do I need a perimeter if the points do not conform to a closed shape? It must be a line. Also, it doesn't accept a set of points as a parameter.